# how to set the gcc compiler version in my makefile when installing ns2?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

while installing ns2 according to the steps mentioned here:
http://stanjuly.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/install-ns2-ns-allinone-2-35-on-ubuntu-11-04-for-beginners/

In Step 4, when i opened my make file, my make file looks like this:

```
    CC=     @CC@ 
    CFLAGS=     @CFLAGS@
    RANLIB=     @RANLIB@
    INSTALL=    @INSTALL@

    #
    # how to compile, link, and name shared libraries
    #

    SHLIB_LD=   @SHLIB_LD@
    SHLIB_CFLAGS=   @SHLIB_CFLAGS@
    SHLIB_SUFFIX=   @SHLIB_SUFFIX@
    SHLD_FLAGS= @DL_LD_FLAGS@
    DL_LIBS=    @DL_LIBS@

    SHLIB_LD_LIBS  = @SHLIB_LD_LIBS@

    #
    # where to install shells, libraries, and includes
    #

    INST_OTCLSH=    @prefix@/bin
    INST_OWISH= @prefix@/bin
    INST_OLIB=  @prefix@/lib
    INST_OLIBSH=    @INST_OLIBSH@
    INST_OINC=  @prefix@/include


    #
    # ------------ you shouldn't need to configure below here -----------------
    #
```

the instructions say that i am supposed to change CC = @CC@ to CC = @CC@ -V 4.7.0 (4.7.0 because when i type gcc --version on my terminal it says):

```
    gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3
```

But when instlaiing ns2 (step5): sudo ./install i get the following error:

```
        config.status: creating Makefile
        rm -f libotcl.a otcl.o
        gcc -V 4.7 -c -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -DUSE_SHM -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I. -I/home/me/ns-

        allinone-2.35/include -I/home/me/ns-allinone-2.35/include -I/home/me/ns-

        allinone-2.35/include -I/include  otcl.c
        gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-V’
        gcc: error: 4.7: No such file or directory
        make: *** [libotcl.a] Error 1
        otcl-1.14 make failed! Exiting ...
```

How am i supposed to modify makefile that i dont get this error? Do i have the gcc compiler installed? I dont understand. I dont know how to check if it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

This means your compiler is not compatible and if you don't want to install
gcc 4.4 than change

> ```
> CC = gcc-4.4
> ```

to

> ```
> CC = @CC@
> ```

in `makefile` and `makefile.in` present in `otcl` folder and also change

> ```
> SHLIB_LD="ld -shared"
> ```

to

> ```
> SHLIB_LD="gcc -shared"
> ```

in `configure` file

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an old version of gcc: (Newer versions dosent work)

`apt-get install gcc-4.4` (4.4 is the older version that I found on my repository)

And change

`CC=     @CC@`

for:

`CC=gcc-4.4`